# Managing Cross-Project Dependencies in Enterprise

Tags: maven

My question has to do with the most effective way to manage third party dependencies across a suite of related projects.  The goal is to maintain organizational "standards" for which major third-party (eg. Hibernate, Spring, Apache Commons, etc.) dependencies to use, without creating unnecessary build overhead.  I'll ask the question after some context.

We have a growing stable of products whose builds are managed by Maven.  At the moment, it includes 3 multi-module webapps and a number standalone "executable" projects and about 20 shared dependencies.  We love Maven and couldn't imagine doings some of the things we're currently able to do without it -- particularly with the shared dependencies.

The shared dependency network is multi-layered and has situations where (for example)

```
Project A    <-----
   ^              |
   |           Project B
   |              ^
   |              |
   |           Project C
   |              ^
   |              |
Project D --------
```

Nothing too crazy or cyclical.

But ... it does create a bit of a fatiguing cascade when building - especially since the project are not closely related enough to be placed in a multi-module master project.

I've come to accept this cascaded build as a fact of life.  That is, when `A` changes, send it's new version to `B` and `D`, but be careful not to build `D` until after `C`, etc.

However, if `A`, `B` and `D` all have a direct, third-party dependency (usually an Apache Commons project or a Spring module), I got tired of re-writing the version number in each project -- and a bit fearful of it getting out of sync between the two projects.

So, on my latest iteration of dependency updates, I created a "framework" project.  It has nothing but a large `<dependencyManagement>` node which "mandates" version numbers of known, common third party dependencies.

As per [Maven recommendations](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies), I made each project in our sprawling empire contain this node:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
      <version>${version.framework}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

It seemed clever at first.  Then, reality set in.

It used to be that if a third party dependency of `Project C` changed, I would only have to update `C` (and then any other projects which depend directly on it -- `D` in the above example).

Now, I have to release the framework, update the framework version in *all* projects and release everything, even if there is no direct impact on some projects.  I can (and sometimes do) skip projects if I know this is the case ... but then the framework version number get off by 0.0.x in some projects.

The new system has it's value -- if more than one third-party dependency changes at once and most projects are affected, I can efficiently push through a large number of changes.

But, ultimately, it seems as if I've traded one problem (repeating the same version number of the same Apache Commons project in multiple projects) with another one (unnecessary project updates).  The old way works well for micro-updates; the new way works well for macro/multi updates.

Did I miss something in "Enterprise Maven 101" that would make this whole setup a lot easier manage?

More to the point: what is the most effective way to manage the version numbers of third party dependencies among such a network of interdependent (but not multi-module) projects?

Comment: Perhaps you should only put truly shared dependencies in your BOM project. That way, if you update a dependency that only affects project-c, then it will only be project-c's pom that changes and project-c that is rebuilt along with it's afferent dependencies. If, however, you upgrade spring in the BOM, then everything that uses the BOM will be updated in turn and every artifact you have will be rebuilt appropriately.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the comment.  I try to restrict entry into the BOM project to third-party dependencies which are used in 3+ of the other projects to keep down the number of trivial updates.  Maybe raising the standard for inclusion would be part of the solution.